# How to compare date columns in 2 pandas dataframe and create a flag basis that

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have 2 dataframes :

1st DF contains data from 1st Jan'21 - 31st Dec'21. Example -
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cBsqJ.png)

2nd DF contains shutdown period data. Example -
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XPcyN.png)

I need to create flag in df1 , choosing start and end date from df2. Expected output -
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Du6Qy.png)

Things I have tried but not working out :

```
dum = []
for i in range(0,df1.shape[0]) :
    tagname = df1['unit'][i]
    day     = df1['Date'][i] 
    
    for j in range(0, df2.shape[0]) :
        if ((tagname == df2['UNIT'][j]) and (df2['STARTDate'][j] <= Date <= df2['EndDate'][j])) :
            dum.append(1)
            break
        else :
            dum.append(0)
            break
```

Please help coders!!

Comment: Please modify the question with the example dataframes instead of images.

Comment: Ensure that `date` columns in those two dataframes are `datetime`.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.